# I want to know the cause of the Segmentation Fault error

Tags: c, compiler-errors

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
int math(int a, int b) {
    if (a > b) {
        printf("%d %d %d", a + b, a - b, a * b);
    }

    else if (b > a) {
        printf("%d %d %d", b + a, b - a, b * a);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int n1, n2;
    scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);
    printf(math(n1, n2));
    return 0;
}
```

A program that takes two integers and produces and outputs a function that converts the results of addition, subtraction, and multiplication of two integers. However, a Segmentation Fault error occurs when the compilation is executed. I want to know the cause of the code.

An error appears even if you create and output addition, subtraction, and multiplication functions respectively.

Comment: The tags you are using are not appropriate for this question. Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Remember to at least read the mouseover on the tags you are using when asking a question.

Comment: Always mention the input for these kind of programs.

Comment: `printf(math(n1, n2));` that's not how `printf` works. [read the manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)

Comment: Your first (and only) argument to printf() is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the printf function is expecting a format string prior to the call to the "math" function.  With that in mind here is a snippet of code with some tweaks to avoid the segmentation fault the original code runs into.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int math(int a, int b) {
    int result = 0;
    if (a > b) {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", a + b, a - b, a * b);
        result = (a + b) + (a - b) + (a * b);
    }

    else if (b > a) {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", b + a, b - a, b * a);
        result = (a + b) + (b - a) + (a * b);
    }
    return result;  /* Since this function is defined to return an integer */}

int main(void) {
    int n1, n2;
    printf("Enter in two integers: ");  /* Aids the user to know what they are supposed to enter */
    scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);
    printf("The result of calling the math function is %d\n", math(n1, n2));    /* Revised the usage of the printf function */
    return 0;
}
```

A couple of things to point out.

- Since the "math" function is defined to return an integer, an integer variable was added to the function to accept a calculated value and then be returned to the statement that called the "math" function.
- The printf statement is corrected so that it contains a formatting string to define what and how data is to be printed out.

Following is a sample of a test run from the terminal.

```
@Dev:~/C_Programs/Console/Formulas/bin/Release$ ./Formulas 
Enter in two integers: 33 45
78 12 1485
The result of calling the math function is 1575
```

Give those tweaks a try to see if it meets the spirit of your project.